# Rails 4 production incorrect assets URI

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline, production

I have a Rails 4 app in production and it does not fetch assets from the expected URI. I understand that in production I should turn off `config.assets.compile` so that Rails does not have to compile assets 'on the fly' and I should instead run `rake assets:precompile`. I have take these steps but Rails, when visited, asks for assets as such

`https://www.example.com/stylesheets/active_admin.css`

when I believe it should be

`https://www.example.com/assets/active_admin-6d86a2c5e39d7fd70dbf26fc211000d5.css`

The fingered printed asset does exist in the correct location and I am able to directly hit that URI and get the file back. What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Try this when precompiling on prod:

`RAILS_ENV=production bin/rake assets:precompile`

More info about assets precompiling at [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#precompiling-assets)

Comment: I am already doing this and they are compiled as expected in /public/assets/<filename>-<fingerprint>.css But rails is not making the correct requests